Do some states allow a substitute for runway base course material, in lieu of the FAA P-209?
I would like to know if, for a runway, some State can allow a substitute for the base course in lieu of the FAA crushed aggregate base course (P-209) defined in FAA AC 150/5370-10.
E.g. Can Nevada allow a base course defined in Nevada DOT Spec?

Please explain what you're referring to when you use the term "base course".  Also, what is an "FAA P 209", please?  Typically, states don't regulate the things that the FAA regulates, i.e. most things in aviation.

Is your question strictly related to airports that need to be certified under FAA Part 139?
